# env: node\r: No such file or directory with cordova cli

Tags: macos, cordova, command-line-interface, cordova-3

When trying to run cordova cli  on OSX get an error

env: node\r: No such file or directory

I got the latest version of cordova from npm so I think it is 3.0.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be that cordova is in dos format

once I converted it to Unix format it seems to work.
I don't get the env: node\r: No such file or directory error.

I used dos2unix to make the change
https://code.google.com/p/rudix/downloads/detail?name=dos2unix-5.3.3-0.pkg

On my machine the cordova file was actually in usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova

Comment: I think they fixed this bug so if you get the latest version everything should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. My problem was from GIT but your answer was instrumental to understand that it was coming from a bad line ending mishap. I added my solution below.

Answer (score 14):

**Solution:**

```
$ brew install dos2unix
$ find /usr/local/lib/node_modules -name "*.js" | xargs sudo dos2unix
```

**Details:**

The problem for OP was to do with Git, However I am taking a moment to mention the quick fix for most of it's cases

The problem will show up if Node tries to execute `.js` file which has windows style line endings. Problem might come from third party npm packages which has `.js` files of that kind.

As @Leo mentioned [Dos2Unix](https://code.google.com/p/rudix/downloads/detail?name=dos2unix-5.3.3-0.pkg) is the answer, Here is the chain of commands for an example situation while I was trying to install [Slack-cli](https://candrholdings.github.io/slack-cli/)

```
> npm install -g slack-cli
> slackcli
env: node\r: No such file or directory
```

The fix looks like

```
> brew install dos2unix
> find /usr/local/lib/node_modules/slack-cli -name "*.js" | xargs sudo dos2unix
> slackcli --help
```

Walla..

Answer (score 4):

On my Mac OS X.

I just ran into the same problem : My files had their line endings changed to CRLF(windows) instead of LS(unix).

It made Cordova and Node unable to compile the project with the error :

> env: node\r: No such file or directory

The culprit was GIT which was on AUTOCRLF I don't know why.
I ran the following command in the terminal :

`git config --global core.autocrlf input`

Then I had to delete the project and reclone it from GIT and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Found this to be the easiest/most global solution.  Ran that config command, recloned the project, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me problem is in installed gulp library in file:

'/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js'

It has '\r' in the end of '#!/usr/bin/env node' line. Version:

"github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0"

It was fixed by setting:

`git config --global core.autocrlf input`

And reloading repository

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to run cordova with sudo (ubuntu 20.04)